# Why are the sprites blurry in Unity Android Game?

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-engine, game-development

I am making a 2D android game in Unity. I imported some png images to Unity, they look fine in the editor but when I play the game in Unity Remote 5 it all gets blurry and pixelated.

Answer (score 1):

Unity Remote simply streams a game video from the Editor onto the target device, and then streams input from the target device back to the Editor. The quality of the stream is often not great.

Have you tried running the game directly on the device?

Comment: Yeah, just now ran it as a standalone app, and the graphics quality is fine. Thanks